TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getApp');
So I was running my application fine as a Chrome instance with the code below.
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Check if the app is running on the web
  if (kIsWeb) {
    print("Running on Web - Initializing Firebase...");
    try {
      await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
      );
      print("Firebase initialized successfully for Web.");
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error initializing Firebase for Web: $e");
    }
  } else {
    print("Not running on Web - Firebase functionality disabled.");
  }

  runApp(
    DevicePreview(
      enabled: !kReleaseMode, // Enabled only in development mode
      builder: (context) => const MyApp(), // Wrap your app
    ),
  );
}

Then, I decided to add a Firebase Test Suit and modified my code, following the documentation:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  if (kIsWeb || Platform.isIOS || Platform.isAndroid) {
    print("Running on Web/iOS/Android - Initializing Firebase...");

    if (kDebugMode) {
      try {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator('localhost', 8080);
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator('localhost', 9099);
        print(
            "Firebase initialized successfully - DEVELOPMENT -  for Web/iOS/Android.");
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    } else {
      try {
        await Firebase.initializeApp(
          options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
        );
        print(
            "Firebase initialized successfully - PRODUCTION -  for Web/iOS/Android.");
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  } else {
    print("Not running on Web/iOS/Android - Firebase functionality disabled.");
  }

  runApp(
    DevicePreview(
      enabled: !kReleaseMode, // Enabled only in development mode
      builder: (context) => const MyApp(), // Wrap your app
    ),
  );
}

and now, in the IDE I get no errors and it should be running fine, but I get this kind of error, and I am not sure how to fix it:
Exception has occurred.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getApp')
packages/firebase_core_web/src/interop/core.dart 59:28               app$
packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 360:48         <fn>
packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 384:21         guardNotInitialized
packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 360:13         app
packages/firebase_core/src/firebase.dart 79:41                       app
packages/cloud_firestore/src/firestore.dart 33:21                    get instance
packages/secret_flutter_project/main.dart 62:36                      <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 610:19  <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 634:23  <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 532:3   _asyncStartSync
packages/secret_flutter_project/main.dart 54:6                       main$
web_entrypoint.dart 24:31                                            <fn>
lib/ui_web/ui_web/initialization.dart 41:15                          <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 610:19  <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 634:23  <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 581:31  <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1676:54                                 runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 204:18                           handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 902:44                           handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 931:13                           _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 707:5                            [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 777:7                            callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                     _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                      _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 186:7   <fn>

Can somebody help me resolve this issue, please? I suspect it has something to do with those libraries, but not sure

So basically one of the problems was that I was initializing Firebase.initializeApp() only in production mode, not in debug mode.
We have to move that function out of the if block, right after WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();.
But the problem persisted.
Then, I downloaded my project from github in a different, new and clean directory - pasted my code - and it was working fine?
So basically, two folders, old with the git in it, and new and clean without git. Both have the same code, exactly the same, but old was giving me the same error, and new was running properly...
I didn't find the cause of this, and moved on.
Here is the proper code, with Firebase Testing Suite:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  if (kIsWeb || Platform.isIOS || Platform.isAndroid) {
    print("Running on Web/iOS/Android - Initializing Firebase...");
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );

    if (kDebugMode) {
      try {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator('localhost', 8080);
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator('localhost', 9099);
        print(
            "Firebase initialized successfully - DEVELOPMENT -  for Web/iOS/Android.");
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    } else {
      print(
          "Firebase initialized successfully - PRODUCTION -  for Web/iOS/Android.");
    }
  } else {
    print("Not running on Web/iOS/Android - Firebase functionality disabled.");
  }

